# Why Event Delegation is counting click my addEventListener("submit") on every click?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, native

**Hello Everyone!**
In this case, I want to make a single page application
and this is always required to add, load, edit or delete HTML element
and then I found some annoying problem,

when every click my event submit is counting that click too,
like I click that submit in the second time, it will result in two time data submitted
and click again that submit in the third time, it will result in three time data submitted, etc.

**my code explanation:**

I have a data table, in every row have a button to edit the current data, when the user clicks that button it will be adding a new form to the page, and this my problem begins, when I submit that form edit the event delegation is counting my event also affected to how many data submitted

```js
var el_tbl_body = document.getElementById("tbody");
el_tbl_body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var this_el = event.target;
    // Handling error
    if (typeof this_el.attributes.id !== "undefined") {
        // Click only work in id="edit-datatable"
        if (this_el.attributes.id.value === "edit-datatable") {
            // This method for holding add another form edit datatable
            // so it will be only one form
            if (document.getElementById("form-edit-datatable") !== null) {
                document.getElementById("form-edit-datatable").parentNode.remove();
            }
            var new_form = document.createElement("div");
            new_form.innerHTML = 
                '<form action="#" method="POST" id="form-edit-datatable">' +
                    '<input type="text" id="edit-name" value="Example value" required/>' +
                    '<input type="submit" id="submit-edit-datatable" value="Ubah data"/>' +
                '<form/>';
            this_el.parentNode.insertBefore(new_form, this_el);
        }
        
        if (document.getElementById("form-edit-datatable") !== null) {

            // The problem is in here
            document.getElementById("form-edit-datatable").addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                console.log("data has been send") 
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
                 <tr>
                     <td>3778</td>
                     <td>John Doe</td>
                     <td>Paris</td>
                     <td><button id="edit-datatable">Edit Data</button></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>2353</td>
                     <td>Eric Samuel</td>
                     <td>Hamburg</td>
                     <td><button id="edit-datatable">Edit Data</button></td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: So on every “click” the code is adding _another_ “submit” handler? As it’s written, that seems expected, as that is what the “click” handler does in the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when `Form Submit` button is clicked, it propagates to `form_wrapper` click listener, that ads another listener and so on.

You can avoid listening `form-wrapper` clicks and simply do:

```
var btn_addNewForm = document.getElementById("add-newForm");
var form_wrapper = document.getElementById("form-wrapper");

btn_addNewForm.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  form_wrapper.innerHTML =
    '<form action="#" method="POST" id="new-form">' +
      '<input type="submit" value="Form Submit"/>'
    '</form>';
  document.getElementById("new-form").addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Data")
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you it's work, I try this method earlier and it doesn't work, but whatever, it's work now :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var btn_addNewForm = document.getElementById("add-newForm");
var form_wrapper = document.getElementById("form-wrapper");

btn_addNewForm.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  form_wrapper.innerHTML =
    '<form action="#" method="POST" id="new-form">' +
      '<input type="submit" value="Form Submit"/>'
    '</form>';
});

// Start Event Delegation
window.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Data")
    })
```

```html
    <button id="add-newForm">Add New Form</button>
    <div id="form-wrapper"></div>
```

See the changes this might help. You can delegate the event of submit to a form or window object.

Comment: sorry I didn't say that I have more than one Form

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
form_wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  document.getElementById("new-form").addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Data")
  });
});
```

to

```
document.getElementById("new-form").addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Data")
  });
```

Comment: And then you will get error, since `new-form` element is not defined yet.